# Can't switch to console using my own compiled kernel

Tags: linux, console, linux-kernel

In my Ubuntu, I can't switch to console through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> using my own compiled kernel, and a black screen appears.

I can switch back through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. Using the default Ubuntu kernel, I can switch normally. `dmesg` has no message about this.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add both kernel versions and your graphic card and driver. Can you see the console during boot?

Comment: kernel-2.6.34 ,nvidia Gforce 9300GS,and the graphic card driver seems has some problem(resolution is low),so I want to switch to console to install mannually.
I Can login X successfully,and during boot console didn't displayed(just ubuntu's purple screen).

Even can't get to console through recovery mode!
when boot through recovery mode, it get stuck in a ubuntu purple screen with:
Loading Linux-2.6.34...
Loading initial ramdisk...

Comment: Do you have your own kernel running under the same Ubuntu installation, or do you have your own configuration for the own kernel.

Comment: @hello.wjx How do you know that `dmesg` has no message about your tty switching issue? Where have you been searching for?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created and populated your `/etc/inittab` appropriately? In particular you'll want these:

```
# Run gettys in standard runlevels
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty1
2:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty2
3:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty3
4:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty4
5:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty5
6:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty6
```

Comment: There is no /etc/inittab by default in ubuntu,I added it following your advice,but it doesn't work, :-( there is no corresponding info in /var/log/messages

Comment: @hello Hmm. IIRC, Ubuntu switched to `upstart` some time ago, perhaps that's the problem. I'll look into how to configure upstart.

Comment: it's switched to upstart,but /etc/inittab should still works because /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf will read that.
It should be a kernel specific issue because ubuntu default kernel is ok on my machine.Maybe some module gets wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, I find tty-configuration/commands in:

```
/etc/default/console-setup:
    ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"

/etc/event.d/tty1:
    # tty1 - getty
    # This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
    exec /sbin/getty 38400 tty1

/etc/init/tty1.conf:
    # tty1 - getty
    # This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
    exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

I don't know how they depend on each other and what to do about them, but suspect, that the setup is managed there.